# LocalTime.MIDNIGHT vs. LocalTime.MIN - is there any difference?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, localdate, localtime

I recently answered some questions using `LocalDate.atStartOfDay()` and `LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIN)`.
I was wondering why there is no `LocalDate.atEndOfDay()` or similar, so one has to use `LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)` in order to get the very last moment (in nanos, I think) of that specific day.

I had a look at the source of `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` and got slightly confused by this:

```java
/**
 * Combines this date with the time of midnight to create a {@code LocalDateTime}
 * at the start of this date.
 * <p>
 * This returns a {@code LocalDateTime} formed from this date at the time of
 * midnight, 00:00, at the start of this date.
 *
 * @return the local date-time of midnight at the start of this date, not null
 */
public LocalDateTime atStartOfDay() {
    return LocalDateTime.of(this, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
}
```

Contrary to my expectation, this method returns a `LocalDateTime` using `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` instead of `LocalTime.MIN`.
Of course, I opened the [OpenJDK source of `LocalTime`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalTime.java) and was sure to find out the difference myself, but I found out there is no difference apart from the name of the constant:

```java
/**
 * Constants for the local time of each hour.
 */
private static final LocalTime[] HOURS = new LocalTime[24];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < HOURS.length; i++) {
        HOURS[i] = new LocalTime(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    MIDNIGHT = HOURS[0];   // <--- == MIN
    NOON = HOURS[12];
    MIN = HOURS[0];        // <--- == MIDNIGHT
    MAX = new LocalTime(23, 59, 59, 999_999_999);
}
```

While I totally understand the presence of `NOON` and `MAX`, I don't really get why there are `MIN` and `MIDNIGHT` when obviously one of them would be enough since they have the very same value.

Can anyone tell me the reason why...

- ... there are two constants having the very same value and
- ... why the code uses `MIDNIGHT` for the start of a day?

Is it just for having something more readable in some situations?
But why isn't `MIN` used in `LocalTime.atStartOfDay()` but rather `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT`?

Comment: _Intuitively_, wouldn't you agree that the sentence "a day starts at midnight" is a _lot_ more natural than "a day starts at the minimum supported local time"? Also, at least for me, a day ends at the same time the next day starts, not at 23:59:59.

Comment: I would agree to that, @Sweeper, but that does not explain the presence of two value-identical constants. Only if the purpose was to have readable constants for different cultures. Possibly, somewhere in the world people consider `MIDNIGHT` the end of a day and somewhere else people consider it the start of a day while you regard it as both. Ok, that will count as *natural* depending on the location, culture or maybe just mood. From a mathematical point of view, `MIN` and `MAX` would suffice, I think (yes, `NOON` would be allowed to stay). And maths is the same all over the world ;-)

Comment: Frankly I would have wished for a constant named `START_OF_DAY`. To me this is preciser as `MIDNIGHT` (not being a native English speaker). And using half-open intervals I would object to an `END_OF_DAY` constant. The day doesn’t end until the next day begins, and the end of the day should be represented as the beginning of the next day, *exclusive*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`MIN` exists to provide the minimum value, which is consistent with other java.time.* classes.

`MIDNIGHT` exists to provide semantic meaning to developers, and as a place to indicate to Javadoc readers that midnight is considered to be at the start of the day (not the end).

Summary, the semantic benefits in code reading outweigh the cost of the extra constant.

(Source: I'm the main java.time.* author)

Comment: Thanks! Good to read a rationale from someone who really wrote that code (or participated in writing it).